# SQL to Mongo Transactions Schema

Tags: javascript, sql, node.js, mongodb, express

I have collection where I collect bills and income information. It consist of:

```
  _id
  billName
  type (usually - income, fixedBill or variableBill)
  amount
  start_date
  end_date
  timestamp
```

And now I need to register payments on this bills.

In SQL I would create a transactions table and register the payments there. For each payment, I would save the `bills._id` as key and then join it whenever I need to see the transactions under one bill.

Now, since I'm using Mongodb, I would like to use the proper way.
How would be the schema for this in Mongo?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can choose either Embedded or Referenced approaches. In the following examples, I assume that the relationship of Transaction - Bills is 1:1.

### Embedded Relationship

```
{
   "_id":ObjectId("TRANSACTION_ID"),
   "bill": {
       "billName": "Bill #1",
       "type": "income",
       "amount": 100,
       "start_date": "xxx",
       "end_date": "yyy",
       "timestamp": "zzz"
     }
}
```

### Referenced Relationship

```
{
   "_id":ObjectId("TRANSACTION_ID"),
   "bill_id": ObjectId("BILL_ID_1")
}
```

*Query*:

`>var result = db.transaction.findOne({"_id":"TRANSACTION_ID"});`
`>db.bills.find({"_id":result["bill_id"]});`

Reference doc: http://www.tutorialspoint.com/mongodb/mongodb_data_modeling.htm